# How to use "Partition By" in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, partition

I am new to use "PARTITION BY" in oracle.  In the table structure that stored multiple addresses for a person as below, how to use "Partition By" in oracle SQL to

1. get the count of record per type per person and
2. get the latest Addr_ID per person per type

| PERSON_ID | ADDR_ID | TYPE | EFF_START_DATE | EFF_END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6207445 | 7390814 | HOME | 2024-02-26 | 4712-12-31 |
| 6207445 | 0042548 | HOME | 2023-05-15 | 4712-12-31 |
| 6207445 | 6462255 | HOME | 2022-01-31 | 4712-12-31 |
| 6207445 | 6462287 | MAIL | 2022-01-31 | 4712-12-31 |
| 6207445 | 0042571 | MAIL | 2023-05-15 | 4712-12-31 |
| 1111111 | 0042578 | MAIL | 2023-05-15 | 4712-12-31 |

Expected Result:

| Person_ID | Type | Rec_Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6207445 | HOME | 3 |
| 6207445 | MAIL | 2 |
| 1111111 | MAIL | 1 |

However, I run the script as below and it gave me different result

```
SELECT person_id, type, 
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id) AS rec_count
FROM PER_PERSON_ADDR_USAGES_F 
WHERE
    person_id = '6207445'
ORDER BY rec_count desc
```

| PERSON_ID | TYPE | REC_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6207445 | HOME | 5 |
| 6207445 | MAIL | 5 |
| 6207445 | HOME | 5 |
| 6207445 | MAIL | 5 |
| 6207445 | HOME | 5 |

What's wrong in my SQL?

Besides, What can I do if I want to get the latest Addr_ID per person per type?

```
SELECT person_id, type, 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id) AS rec_count
FROM PER_PERSON_ADDR_USAGES_F 
WHERE
    to_number(rn) > 1
ORDER BY rec_count desc
```

I try this but failed as below:

```
Query Execution started at Mon Feb 26 15:58:14 AEDT 2024
Error while executing the query:
ORA-06550: line 15, column 13:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "REC_COUNT": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 7, column 17:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Any idea what's wrong in my SQL?

Comment: Please clarify, what do you mean by get the latest addr_id per person per type? Please include your expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytic functions work over the entire result set and return exactly the same number of rows of output as there are of input; if you specify `PARTITION BY` then the function will split the result set up into different partitions and calculate the result within that partition but there will still be a one-to-one correspondence between the input and output rows.

If you want to aggregate so that you only produce one row per partition then do not use analytic functions and use `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT person_id,
       type, 
       COUNT(*) AS rec_count
FROM   PER_PERSON_ADDR_USAGES_F 
GROUP BY person_id, type
ORDER BY rec_count DESC
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PER_PERSON_ADDR_USAGES_F (PERSON_ID, ADDR_ID, TYPE, EFF_START_DATE, EFF_END_DATE) AS
SELECT 6207445, '7390814', 'HOME', DATE '2024-02-26', DATE '4712-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6207445, '0042548', 'HOME', DATE '2023-05-15', DATE '4712-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6207445, '6462255', 'HOME', DATE '2022-01-31', DATE '4712-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6207445, '6462287', 'MAIL', DATE '2022-01-31', DATE '4712-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6207445, '0042571', 'MAIL', DATE '2023-05-15', DATE '4712-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1111111, '0042578', 'MAIL', DATE '2023-05-15', DATE '4712-12-31' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| PERSON_ID | TYPE | REC_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6207445 | HOME | 3 |
| 6207445 | MAIL | 2 |
| 1111111 | MAIL | 1 |

If you want to find the latest address then use `KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ...)`:

```sql
SELECT person_id,
       type, 
       MAX(addr_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY eff_start_date) AS addr_id,
       COUNT(*) AS rec_count
FROM   PER_PERSON_ADDR_USAGES_F 
GROUP BY person_id, type
ORDER BY rec_count DESC
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| PERSON_ID | TYPE | ADDR_ID | REC_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6207445 | HOME | 7390814 | 3 |
| 6207445 | MAIL | 0042571 | 2 |
| 1111111 | MAIL | 0042578 | 1 |

Alternatively, use analytic functions and then filter to only get the first row of each partition:

```sql
SELECT person_id,
       type, 
       addr_id,
       rec_count
FROM   (
  SELECT person_id,
         type, 
         addr_id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id, type ORDER BY eff_start_date DESC)
           AS rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id, type) AS rec_count
  FROM   PER_PERSON_ADDR_USAGES_F 
)
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER BY rec_count DESC
```

Which outputs the same as the previous query.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0-SZfbtd)

Answer (score 0):

Partition by similar to group by, just mention which columns you want to group by

If you want to group by the type also, you need to include the type

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id) AS rec_count
```

This means you want to group by *person_id*, but *type* is not included.

So, please include the *type* as below

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id, type) AS rec_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option to get result answering both questions:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    PER_PERSON_ADDR_USAGES_F (PERSON_ID, ADDR_ID, TYPE, EFF_START_DATE, EFF_END_DATE) AS
        ( Select    6207445, '7390814', 'HOME', DATE '2024-02-26', DATE '4712-12-31' From Dual Union All
          Select    6207445, '0042548', 'HOME', DATE '2023-05-15', DATE '4712-12-31' From Dual Union All 
          Select    6207445, '6462255', 'HOME', DATE '2022-01-31', DATE '4712-12-31' From Dual Union All
          Select    6207445, '6462287', 'MAIL', DATE '2022-01-31', DATE '4712-12-31' From Dual Union All
          Select    6207445, '0042571', 'MAIL', DATE '2023-05-15', DATE '4712-12-31' From Dual Union All
          Select    1111111, '0042578', 'MAIL', DATE '2023-05-15', DATE '4712-12-31' From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--      M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT    PERSON_ID, TYPE, PERSON_TYPE_CNT "REC_COUNT", PERSON_TYPE_LAST_ADDR "LAST ADDR_ID"
FROM    ( SELECT    PERSON_ID,  
                    TYPE,
                    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID, TYPE) AS PERSON_TYPE_CNT,
                    ADDR_ID,
                    Case When Max(EFF_START_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY PERSON_ID, TYPE) = EFF_START_DATE 
                         Then ADDR_ID
                    End AS PERSON_TYPE_LAST_ADDR, 
                    EFF_START_DATE, 
                    EFF_END_DATE
          FROM      PER_PERSON_ADDR_USAGES_F 
        )
Where    PERSON_TYPE_LAST_ADDR Is Not Null
Order By PERSON_TYPE_CNT
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
 PERSON_ID TYPE  REC_COUNT LAST ADDR_ID
---------- ---- ---------- ------------
   1111111 MAIL          1 0042578
   6207445 MAIL          2 0042571
   6207445 HOME          3 7390814        */
```

NOTE: Partition By works as Group By but the result is present in every row. Ordinary aggregation with Group By results in as many rows as there are distinct groups.
Case expression is used to determine row with last ADDR_ID so it could be used as a filter in outer query.